# Adding a letter legend to a set of images

Tags: floats, positioning, minipage

In a `llncs` LaTeX document, I have five images arranged in this order

```
    |     | |     |
  x |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     |
```

I basically want to put a .png image representing a letter legend of the images where the `x` is, i.e.:

```
 |a|b|
|c|d|e|
```

The code I currently have written is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{fig_a}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{fig_b}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.1cm}

\begin{minipage}[]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{fig_c}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{fig_d}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{fig_e}    
\end{minipage}
\caption{(a) Lorem ipsum (b) dolor sit amet (c) consectetur adipiscing elit (d) Mauris ut sollicitudin (e) neque}
\label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}
```

How can I place the letter legend?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `tabular` within `figure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \raisebox{13mm}{\makebox[0.30\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
       &(a)&(b)\\[1.5ex]
    (c)&(d)&(e)
    \end{tabular}%
    }}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.1cm}

\begin{minipage}[]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}    
\end{minipage}
\caption{(a) Lorem ipsum (b) dolor sit amet (c) consectetur adipiscing
  elit (d) Mauris ut sollicitudin (e) neque}
\label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \raisebox{13mm}{\makebox[0mm][r]{%
    \tabcolsep0mm%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
       &(a)&   &(b)&   \\[1.5ex]
    (c)&   &(d)&   &(e)
    \end{tabular}%
    \quad
    }}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.1cm}

\begin{minipage}[]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}
  \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}    
\end{minipage}
\caption{(a) Lorem ipsum (b) dolor sit amet (c) consectetur adipiscing
  elit (d) Mauris ut sollicitudin (e) neque}
\label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```